# msxml6.dll error '80072ee2' The operation timed out

Tags: .net, iis, asp-classic

I have old code that call a .net webservices that throws this error if the .net code is cold (not in memory)

```
msxml6.dll error '80072ee2' 

The operation timed out
```

A reload always fixes this

Can I change the timeout?
Can I stop the .net from going cold?
Can I trap the error in classic asp and do reload to stop the user see the error?

any other idea to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Anthony for the hint -pkb

Here is the documentation and the link to MSDN

> `oServerXMLHTTPRequest.setTimeouts(resolveTimeout, connectTimeout, sendTimeout, receiveTimeout)`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `resolveTimeout` A *long integer*. The value is applied to mapping host names (such as "www.microsoft.com") to IP addresses; the default
> value is infinite, meaning no timeout.
>
> `connectTimeout` A *long integer*. The value is applied to establishing a communication socket with the target server, with a
> default timeout value of 60 seconds.
>
> `sendTimeout` A *long integer*. The value applies to sending an individual packet of request data (if any) on the communication socket
> to the target server. A large request sent to a server will normally
> be broken up into multiple packets; the send timeout applies to
> sending each packet individually. The default value is 30 seconds.
>
> `receiveTimeout` A *long integer*. The value applies to receiving a packet of response data from the target server. Large responses will
> be broken up into multiple packets; the receive timeout applies to
> fetching each packet of data off the socket. The default value is 30
> seconds.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760403(VS.85,lightweight).aspx

Answer (score 7):

The `ServerXMLHTTTPRequest` object has a setTimeouts method:-

```
xhr.setTimeouts 30000, 60000, 30000, 120000
```

This sets the receive timeout (that last number) to 2 minutes (the default is 30 seconds) its this value you want to play with.